# Function indexing dataset and variable of interest

Tags: r, function

I am just started learning programming and I have a question that is probably easy for you. 
I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
df <- data.frame(id= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), time=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),y = rnorm(9), x1 = LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 9 )], x2 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),c2 = rnorm(9))
df
#    id time     y      x1 x2     c2
# 1  1    1  0.6364831  A  0 -0.066480473
# 2  1    2  0.4476390  B  0  0.161372575
# 3  1    3  1.5113458  C  0  0.343956178
# 4  2    1  0.3532957  D  0  0.279987147
# 5  2    2  0.3401402  E  1 -0.462635393
# 6  2    3 -0.3160222  F  0  0.338454940
# 7  3    1 -1.3797158  G  1 -0.621169576
# 8  3    2  1.4026640  H  1 -0.005690801
# 9  3    3  0.2958363  I  1 -0.176488132
```

I am writing a function with multiple steps. I would like the feed the function with two elements the dataset and the variable of interest.

However, the function breaks down when I try to `dcast` it as it fails to individuate the variable. The crucial step of the function looks something like this.

```
testfun<-function(df,var)
{
newdf <- dcast(dataset,id+time~ x1, value.var = var) %>%  # note this should be the variable of interest that i feed into the function 
distinct()
return(newdf)
}
df2<-testfun(df,y)
```

Can anyone help me and explain how can I create a function where I index both a dataset and a function?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Are you sure you are using `dcast` correctly ? What is your expected output of how `newdf` should look? How do you run this outside the function `dcast(dataset,id+time~ x1, value.var = var)` ?

Comment: Since you’re using dplyr, use the corresponding tidyr function instead of `dcast`. That allows you to pass in variables.

Comment: Because this `dcast` is only a step in a more complex function. I need to apply this to multiple datasets and multiple variables, hence I wanted to write a function doing all the operations at once to make the script cleaner. @RonakShah

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I would prefer using dcast as it is a very big dataset and it is quicker. but how would it look like the dplyr command producing the same identical output?

Comment: Do you really want your data to look like this? `dcast(df,id+time~ x1, value.var = "y") `

Comment: Yes I do, this is just an example and in reality, `x1` is a categorical string variable. I have edited the df to make it less "ugly". I have a different y score for each category x1 and I need to make the data wide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass column name as a string the function would work as it is

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

testfun1<-function(df,var) {    
  newdf <- dcast(df,id+time~ x1, value.var = var) %>% distinct()
  return(newdf)
}

testfun1(df, "y")
```

However, if you want to pass unquoted variable as input you can use

```
testfun2<-function(df,var) {
  var1 <- deparse(substitute(var))
  newdf <- dcast(df,id+time~ x1, value.var = var1) %>% distinct()
  return(newdf)
}

testfun2(df, y)
```

---

The equivalent `tidyr` function mentioned by @Konrad Rudolph  is `pivot_wider` which would work with both types of inputs.

```
testfun3 <-function(df,var) {
    new_df <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = x1, values_from = y)
    return(new_df)
}
testfun3(df, y)
testfun3(df, "y")
```

Comment: Sorry I have a follow-up question. Another line of the function is something like this `testfun2(dataset,var){step<-unique(setDT(dataset)[var==1 & c2>0,.(x1)])}` This time passing the column name as a string does not seem to work. ` as `testfun(df, "x2")` does not work.... do you know how can I identify the variable in this case?

Comment: Yes, search for non-standard evaluation. How to pass variables usually depends on what you want to do l. Probably using `get` would help here.